# Get average length of values of a column (from a hive table) in spark along with data types

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive

Task: Get data types of a table (in hive) and the average length of values of each column.

I'm trying to do the above task in spark using scala.
Firstly I did
`val table = spark.sql("desc table")`
The output has three columns, col_name, datatype, comment.
And then, I tried to get only the column values as a comma-separated string.

`val col_string = table.select("col_name").rdd.map(i => "avg(length(trim("+i(0).toString+")))").collect.mkString(", ")`

Now, I can use this string in another query to get the average length of all columns like given below, but the output dataframe has as many numbers of columns as the table, I don't know how to join it with the `table` dataframe.

`val tbl_length = spark.sql("select " + col_string + " from schema.table")`

I've looked at transposing the second dataframe, that looks not efficient, and hard for me to grasp as a beginner in spark and scala.

Is my method above is good/efficient one? if there is a better way please suggest.
Even if there is a better way, can you also please explain how I can join two such datasets of row=>column.

Input table:
col1| col2| col3
Ac| 123| 0
Defg| 23456| 0

Expected output
column_name| data_type| avg_length
col1| String| 3
col2| Int| 4
col3| Int| 1

Comment: Share some sample ip and op.

Comment: @SathiyanS added the sample input and expected output. Please check now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this-

```scala
  val table = spark.catalog.getTable("df")
    val df = spark.sql(s"select * from ${table.name}")
    df.show(false)
    /**
      * +---+----+
      * |id |name|
      * +---+----+
      * |1  |abc1|
      * |2  |abc2|
      * |3  |abc3|
      * +---+----+
      */
    val aggs = df.columns.map(f => avg(length(trim(col(f)))).as(f))
    val values = df.agg(aggs.head, aggs.tail: _*).head.getValuesMap[Double](df.columns).values.toSeq
    df.schema.map(sf => (sf.name, sf.dataType)).zip(values).map{ case ((name, dt), value) => (name, dt.simpleString, value)}
      .toDF("column_name", "data_type", "avg_length")
      .show(false)

    /**
      * +-----------+---------+----------+
      * |column_name|data_type|avg_length|
      * +-----------+---------+----------+
      * |id         |bigint   |1.0       |
      * |name       |string   |4.0       |
      * +-----------+---------+----------+
      */
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. it's working although a little bit of explanation would have been better. for e.g. "df" in your first line is actually "schema.table". 
I have one doubt, ```val df = spark.sql(s"select * from ${table.name}")``` wouldn't this take all the contents of table into memory? what if I have millions of rows in my table, would this be an efficent solution? please clarify.

Comment: `val df = spark.sql(s"select * from ${table.name}")` this will never load the data into memory due to lazy nature of spark. the data will be loaded when we compute the average length of all columns which is must to do operation. I believe this is best performant way to achieve your requirement. Please feel free to accept + upvote if it helps